# What is the easiest way to wrap Promise in ES6?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm using a promise-based package (Axios) for making HTTP requests. So, I have a code like this:

```
axios.all(/*many generated requests*/).then((res) => {
      //success handler
    }).catch((err) => {
      //error handler
    });
```

I want to write a simple wrapper which generates and sends all the requests, but still has the same syntax. It will make the code above look like:

```
manyReqsWrapper(args).then((res) => {
      //success handler
    }).catch((err) => {
      //error handler
    });
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `function mayReqsWrapper(args) { return axios.all(...); }`?

Comment: @torazaburo Oh, that's really works. I've tried it, but since I had a error in another part of code, I thought, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promises are simple values and can be `return`ed from functions like everything else. You seem to be looking for

```
function mayReqsWrapper(args) {
    return axios.all(/* whatever you need */);
}
```